# R error - Check for Remote errors returning multiple node issues

Tags: r, chi-squared, unmarked-package

I am currently trying to run goodness of fit tests for data in the `unmarked` package. To do this I am using code written in the associated google group. This relies on parboot to assess the goodness of fit of the model. It then produces a Chi squared P value and C-hat value.

Strangely when I only perform >90 simulations of the model do I get the following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    3 nodes produced errors;
>   first error: could not find function "mb.chisq.RN"

Below this number of simulations, the error is not encountered and the statistic can be computed.

I first run; `mb.chisq.RN`

```
mb.chisq.RN <- function (mod, print.table = TRUE, maxK=50, 

...){
  y.raw <- mod@data@y
  N.raw <- nrow(y.raw)
  na.raw <- apply(X = y.raw, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(i) all(is.na(i)))
  y.data <- y.raw[!na.raw, ]
  N <- N.raw - sum(na.raw)
  T <- ncol(y.data)
  K <- 0:maxK
  det.hist <- apply(X = y.data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(i) paste(i, 
                                                                    collapse = ""))
  preds.lam <- predict(mod, type = "state")$Predicted
  preds.p <- matrix(data = predict(mod, type = "det")$Predicted, 
                    ncol = T, byrow = TRUE)
  out.hist <- data.frame(det.hist, preds.lam)
  un.hist <- unique(det.hist)
  n.un.hist <- length(un.hist)
  na.vals <- length(grep(pattern = "NA", x = un.hist)) > 0
  if (na.vals) {
    id.na <- grep(pattern = "NA", x = un.hist)
    id.det.hist.na <- grep(pattern = "NA", x = det.hist)
    cohort.na <- sort(un.hist[id.na])
    n.cohort.na <- length(cohort.na)
    unique.na <- gsub(pattern = "NA", replacement = "N", 
                      x = cohort.na)
    na.visits <- sapply(strsplit(x = unique.na, split = ""), 
                        FUN = function(i) paste(ifelse(i == "N", 1, 0), collapse = ""))
    names(cohort.na) <- na.visits
    n.hist.missing.cohorts <- table(na.visits)
    n.missing.cohorts <- length(n.hist.missing.cohorts)
    out.hist.na <- out.hist[id.det.hist.na, ]
    out.hist.na$det.hist <- droplevels(out.hist.na$det.hist)
    just.na <- sapply(X = out.hist.na$det.hist, FUN = function(i) gsub(pattern = "1", 
                                                                       replacement = "0", x = i))
    out.hist.na$coh <- sapply(X = just.na, FUN = function(i) gsub(pattern = "NA", 
                                                                  replacement = "1", x = i))
    freqs.missing.cohorts <- table(out.hist.na$coh)
    na.freqs <- table(det.hist[id.det.hist.na])
    preds.p.na <- preds.p[id.det.hist.na, ]
    cohort.not.na <- sort(un.hist[-id.na])
    out.hist.not.na <- out.hist[-id.det.hist.na, ]
    out.hist.not.na$det.hist <- droplevels(out.hist.not.na$det.hist)
    n.cohort.not.na <- length(cohort.not.na)
    n.sites.not.na <- length(det.hist) - length(id.det.hist.na)
    preds.p.not.na <- preds.p[-id.det.hist.na, ]
  }
  else {
    cohort.not.na <- sort(un.hist)
    out.hist.not.na <- out.hist
    preds.p.not.na <- preds.p
    n.cohort.not.na <- length(cohort.not.na)
    n.sites.not.na <- length(det.hist)
  }
  if (n.cohort.not.na > 0) {
    exp.freqs <- rep(NA, n.cohort.not.na)
    names(exp.freqs) <- cohort.not.na
    for (i in 1:n.cohort.not.na) {
      eq.solved <- rep(NA, n.sites.not.na)
      select.hist <- cohort.not.na[i]
      strip.hist <- unlist(strsplit(select.hist, split = ""))
      hist.mat <- new.hist.mat <- new.hist.mat1 <- new.hist.mat0 <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.sites.not.na, ncol = T)
      for (j in 1:n.sites.not.na) {

        if (n.sites.not.na == 1) {
          hist.mat[j,] <- preds.p.not.na
        } else {hist.mat[j,] <- preds.p.not.na[j,]}

        #Pr(y.ij=1|K)
        p.k.mat <- sapply(hist.mat[j,],function(r){1-(1-r)^K})

        new.hist.mat1[j,] <- dpois(K,out.hist.not.na[j, "preds.lam"]) %*% p.k.mat
        new.hist.mat0[j,] <- dpois(K,out.hist.not.na[j, "preds.lam"]) %*% (1-p.k.mat)

        new.hist.mat[j,] <- ifelse(strip.hist == "1", 
                                   new.hist.mat1[j,], ifelse(strip.hist == "0", 
                                                             new.hist.mat0[j,], 0))
        combo.lam.p <- paste(new.hist.mat[j, ], collapse = "*")
        eq.solved[j] <- eval(parse(text = as.expression(combo.lam.p)))
      }
      exp.freqs[i] <- sum(eq.solved, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    freqs <- table(out.hist.not.na$det.hist)
    out.freqs <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.cohort.not.na, ncol = 4)
    colnames(out.freqs) <- c("Cohort", "Observed", "Expected", 
                             "Chi-square")
    rownames(out.freqs) <- names(freqs)
    out.freqs[, 1] <- 0
    out.freqs[, 2] <- freqs
    out.freqs[, 3] <- exp.freqs
    out.freqs[, 4] <- ((out.freqs[, "Observed"] - out.freqs[, 
                                                            "Expected"])^2)/out.freqs[, "Expected"]
  }
  if (na.vals) {
    missing.cohorts <- list()
    if (!is.matrix(preds.p.na)) {
      preds.p.na <- matrix(data = preds.p.na, nrow = 1)
    }
    for (m in 1:n.missing.cohorts) {
      select.cohort <- out.hist.na[which(out.hist.na$coh == 
                                           names(freqs.missing.cohorts)[m]), ]
      select.preds.p.na <- preds.p.na[which(out.hist.na$coh == 
                                              names(freqs.missing.cohorts)[m]), ]
      if (!is.matrix(select.preds.p.na)) {
        select.preds.p.na <- matrix(data = select.preds.p.na, 
                                    nrow = 1)
      }
      select.preds.p.na[, gregexpr(pattern = "N", text = gsub(pattern = "NA", 
                                                              replacement = "N", x = select.cohort$det.hist[1]))[[1]]] <- 1
      n.total.sites <- nrow(select.cohort)
      freqs.na <- table(droplevels(select.cohort$det.hist))
      cohort.na.un <- sort(unique(select.cohort$det.hist))
      n.hist.na <- length(freqs.na)
      exp.na <- rep(NA, n.hist.na)
      names(exp.na) <- cohort.na.un
      for (i in 1:n.hist.na) {
        n.sites.hist <- freqs.na[i]
        eq.solved <- rep(NA, n.total.sites)
        select.hist <- gsub(pattern = "NA", replacement = "N", 
                            x = cohort.na.un[i])
        strip.hist <- unlist(strsplit(select.hist, split = ""))
        hist.mat <- new.hist.mat <- new.hist.mat1 <-new.hist.mat0 <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.total.sites, ncol = T)
        for (j in 1:n.total.sites) {

          hist.mat[j, ] <- select.preds.p.na[j, ]

          #Pr(y.ij=1|K)
          p.k.mat <- sapply(hist.mat[j,],function(r){1-(1-r)^K})

          new.hist.mat1[j,] <- dpois(K,select.cohort[j, "preds.lam"]) %*% p.k.mat
          new.hist.mat0[j,] <- dpois(K,select.cohort[j, "preds.lam"]) %*% (1-p.k.mat)

          new.hist.mat[j,] <- ifelse(strip.hist == "1", 
                                     new.hist.mat1[j,], ifelse(strip.hist == "0", 
                                                               new.hist.mat0[j,], 1))
          combo.lam.p <- paste(new.hist.mat[j, ], collapse = "*")
          eq.solved[j] <- eval(parse(text = as.expression(combo.lam.p)))
        }
        exp.na[i] <- sum(eq.solved, na.rm = TRUE)
      }
      out.freqs.na <- matrix(NA, nrow = n.hist.na, ncol = 4)
      colnames(out.freqs.na) <- c("Cohort", "Observed", 
                                  "Expected", "Chi-square")
      rownames(out.freqs.na) <- cohort.na.un
      out.freqs.na[, 1] <- m
      out.freqs.na[, 2] <- freqs.na
      out.freqs.na[, 3] <- exp.na
      out.freqs.na[, 4] <- ((out.freqs.na[, "Observed"] - 
                               out.freqs.na[, "Expected"])^2)/out.freqs.na[, 
                                                                           "Expected"]
      missing.cohorts[[m]] <- list(out.freqs.na = out.freqs.na)
    }
  }
  if (na.vals) {
    chisq.missing <- do.call("rbind", lapply(missing.cohorts, 
                                             FUN = function(i) i$out.freqs.na))
    if (n.cohort.not.na > 0) {
      chisq.unobs.det <- N - sum(out.freqs[, "Expected"]) - 
        sum(chisq.missing[, "Expected"])
      chisq.table <- rbind(out.freqs, chisq.missing)
    }
    else {
      chisq.unobs.det <- N - sum(chisq.missing[, "Expected"])
      chisq.table <- chisq.missing
    }
  }
  else {
    chisq.unobs.det <- N - sum(out.freqs[, "Expected"])
    chisq.na <- 0
    chisq.table <- out.freqs
  }
  chisq <- sum(chisq.table[, "Chi-square"]) + chisq.unobs.det
  if (print.table) {
    out <- list(chisq.table = chisq.table, chi.square = chisq, 
                model.type = "single-season")
  }
  else {
    out <- list(chi.square = chisq, model.type = "single-season")
  }
  class(out) <- "mb.chisq"
  return(out)

    }
```

Which will successfuly compute a Chi squared value.
I then run the test.

```
mb.gof.test.RN <- function (mod, nsim = 100, plot.hist = TRUE, ...){
  mod.table <- mb.chisq.RN(mod)
  out <- parboot(mod, statistic = function(i) mb.chisq.RN(i)$chi.square, 
                 nsim = nsim)
  p.value <- sum(out@t.star >= out@t0)/nsim
  if (p.value == 0) {
    p.display <- paste("<", 1/nsim)
  }
  else {
    p.display = paste("=", round(p.value, digits = 4))
  }
  if (plot.hist) {
    hist(out@t.star, main = paste("Bootstrapped MacKenzie and Bailey fit statistic (", 
                                  nsim, " samples)", sep = ""), xlim = range(c(out@t.star, 
                                                                               out@t0)), xlab = paste("Simulated statistic ", "(observed = ", 
                                                                                                      round(out@t0, digits = 2), ")", sep = ""))
    title(main = bquote(paste(italic(P), " ", .(p.display))), 
          line = 0.5)
    abline(v = out@t0, lty = "dashed", col = "red")
  }
  c.hat.est <- out@t0/mean(out@t.star)
  gof.out <- list(model.type = mod.table$model.type, chisq.table = mod.table$chisq.table, 
                  chi.square = mod.table$chi.square, t.star = out@t.star, 
                  p.value = p.value, c.hat.est = c.hat.est, nsim = nsim)
  class(gof.out) <- "mb.chisq"
  return(gof.out)
}

>mb.gof.test.RN(fm9)
```

which produces the following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    3 nodes produced errors;
>   first error: could not find function "mb.chisq.RN"

I'm not entirely sure why this error only occurs above a certain number of simulations so any pointers would be greatly received.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing a function to `parboot` instead of a value (hidden in a function)?

Comment: I wouldn't know what a passing function is. I'm very new to R and I have simply taken this code as recommended by others on the google group. Would you be able to provide an example of how it would be implemented?